# Why is in LaTeX just the number figure of even numbers?

Tags: floats, number

```
\documentclass{article}%
%
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{mathptmx}%      ‎
\usepackage{subcaption}%
\usepackage{amsmath}%‎‎
\usepackage{booktabs}%
\usepackage{amsthm}%‎‎
\usepackage{amssymb}%
%‎
\begin{document}‎
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{.55\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=6.6cm]{example-image-a}
\subcaption{Exact solution}
\end{subfigure}‎
\begin{subfigure}{.55\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=6.6cm]{example-image-a}
\subcaption{N=2}
\end{subfigure}‎
\begin{subfigure}{.55\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=6.6cm]{example-image-a}
\subcaption{N=4}
\end{subfigure}‎‎‎
\begin{subfigure}{.45\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=5.5cm]{example-image-a}
\subcaption{t=0.5}
\end{subfigure}‎
\caption{Exact and discretized solutions for N=2 and 4. Exact and estimated solutions with t=0.5 for Example 1.}‎
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: can you add some words to your question to make it clear what your question is (the question in the title is not clear at all) which even numbers? Also edit the example to be a complete document that shows the problem. Please delete all packages not required in the example, but add `\documentclass...` and change the images to be `example-image.eps` so that we can run the file and debug your problem.

Comment: Could it be possible that your code comtains some invisible characters? Probably an annotated screenshot of your current output or a sketch of the desired output could help clarify your question.

Answer (score 2):

your document produces multiple errors of the form

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character  (U+200E)
```

as it has the Unicode Right-to-left control mark in several places.

It would be best to delete them but you can add

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{200E}{}
```

to the top of the file so that that character does nothing, then your document runs without error although with warnings that these example widths are too wide but probably your real images are a different size so I am ignoring that. Also I do not know which "even numbers" you refer to in the title of the question.

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{200E}{}

\documentclass{article}%
%
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{mathptmx}%      ‎
\usepackage{subcaption}%
\usepackage{amsmath}%‎‎
\usepackage{booktabs}%
\usepackage{amsthm}%‎‎
\usepackage{amssymb}%
%‎
\begin{document}‎
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{.55\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=6.6cm]{example-image-a}
\subcaption{Exact solution}
\end{subfigure}‎
\begin{subfigure}{.55\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=6.6cm]{example-image-a}
\subcaption{N=2}
\end{subfigure}‎
\begin{subfigure}{.55\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=6.6cm]{example-image-a}
\subcaption{N=4}
\end{subfigure}‎‎‎
\begin{subfigure}{.45\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=5.5cm]{example-image-a}
\subcaption{t=0.5}
\end{subfigure}‎
\caption{Exact and discretized solutions for N=2 and 4. Exact and estimated solutions with t=0.5 for Example 1.}‎
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]